# Compiler error in method overloading with varags argument in Java

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions

I have two functions like this:

```
String getMessage(String code, Object... objects);
String getMessage(Locale locale, String code, Object... objects);
```

And I try to call the first function without varags argument:

```
myClass.getMessage("online.order");
```

I get this compiler error:

> Error: java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted
>   to java.util.Locale

It tries to use the second function and I do not understand why?

**Update: Context of the code**

This is the interface that define those two functions:

```
public interface MyMessageProvider {
    String getMessage(String code, Object... objects);
    String getMessage(Locale locale, String code, Object... objects);
}
```

This is the actual class that implements that interface and also extends Spring `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`

```
public class CustomMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource implements MyMessageProvider {
    public static final String BEAN_NAME = "messageSource";

    public static CustomMessageSource getInstance() {
        return (CustomMessageSource) SpringApplicationContext.getBean(BEAN_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(String code, Object[] objects) {
        return getMessage(getCurrentLocale(), code, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(Locale locale, String code, Object... objects) {
        return getMessage(code, objects, code, locale);
    }
}
```

And I call getMessage in a class like this:

```
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private CustomMessageSource messageSource;

    public String createSomeMessage(){
        messageSource.getMessage("online.order");
    }

}
```

I can solve the issue by adding `String getMessage(String code)` to the interface/implementation. The compile error does not makes sence to me same as you guys. But, I am getting the compile error!

Comment: Are you sure your build is up to date? Try doing `Project -> Clean`, if the same error still appears, [edit] in some more context. The above code will _not_ produce the error described.

Comment: @MattClark, I cleaned the project but still I am getting same compile error. The only solution I could find so far is define a new function `String getMessage(String code)` and call the first function inside it with null as varags.

Comment: looks strange, the first method should get invoked, are there other overloaded methods?

Comment: Whelp, you are going to have to [edit] in some additional context, I just tried this in my IDE, and am unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added additional contexts to the question. The code runs in Spring boot framework.

Comment: The funny thing is my IDE (intelliJ) can find the correct function when I click on function name. But the compiler gives error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the overridden method slightly changes a parent method signature from

```
public String getMessage(String code, Object... objects)
```

to

```
public String getMessage(String code, Object[] objects)
```

For the compiler, it doesn't matter, it considers `Object...` as a thing that should be transformed to an `Object[]` and will make that conversion (after the compile stage is completed, there is no any `Object...` stuff).

Whereas for us, it does matter. We have to follow a method signature exactly. To invoke the method, you have to pass an array or `null` there:

```
instance.getMessage("code", new Object[]{});
instance.getMessage("code", null);
```

Comment: yes, I found the issue at the same time :) But the compiler did not tell me anything about this issue/

Comment: @Arashsoft, It considers `Object...` and `Object[]` equal, so the overriding passed without issues.

Comment: But this post shows that they are not equal. It is compiler bug :)

Comment: @Arashsoft, they are not equal only for us in a syntax light

Answer (score 0):

OMG! I found the issue myself. The issue is in the implementation class where I overrided

```
String getMessage(String code, Object... objects);
```

with

```
String getMessage(String code, Object[] objects)
```

It works fine without any issue but when I want to call getMessage without any varags argument, the override cannot handle it.